# when declare final instance why i must initialize it?

Tags: java, final

I am getting error ***Variable "type" might not have been initialized*** for the following code:

```
public class Ingredient {

    private final String  id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    public static enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }

    ... 

}
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Because you must assign a value to the fields, and you're not, i.e. you have not "initialized" the fields, just like the error says.

Comment: Because final variables can only be initialized directly from declaration or from constructor, you are not initialized directly from declaration, so you need a constructor

Comment: it is specified that way in [8.3.1.2. final Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2): "A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned and moreover not definitely unassigned at the end of every constructor of the class in which it is declared, or a compile-time error occurs"

Comment: You don't have to 'create constructor', but you do have to initialize it, as enums don't have a default value.

Answer (score 1):

`final` indicates a creation of a constant, i.e. the variable which value will not be changed, thus the word `final`.
[GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-keyword-java/) has a good article on that. Quoting:

> When a variable is declared with final keyword, its value can’t be modified, essentially, a constant. This also means that you must initialize a final variable. If the final variable is a reference, this means that the variable cannot be re-bound to reference another object, but internal state of the object pointed by that reference variable can be changed i.e. you can add or remove elements from final array or final collection. It is good practice to represent final variables in all uppercase, using underscore to separate words.

If you do not initialize `final` variable, it wouldn't make sense to have it at all, as you will not be able to change it from non-initialized state.